# javax.servlet.Filter blocks iFrame request

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters, stripes

My application implements the `javax.servlet.Filter` interface. But I've got a weird case. One of my `ActionBean` instances is returning response to one jsp, this jsp contains an `<iframe>` tag. in this tag, `src` attribute has same request uri as this jsp but with change in param values. But the uri inside `<iframe>` is not being requested.

I've tried to remove `Filter` from my application. Then it works fine. So what should I do while using `Filter` interface ?

Comment: So what does the `Filter` actually do?

Comment: @DavidGrant Grant Filters are preprocessors of the request before it reaches a servlet, and/or postprocessors of the response leaving a servlet. It is used to intercept, modify or examine request, response, their header or invocation of requests.

Comment: I know that!  I meant your filter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved...

The thing I need to take care about is I can not `Redirect` the request. I've to `forward` it. And it was out of my mind.

`Filter` can not harm your request if you use it wisely.